# Sort dict of name and float

Tags: python

I do not know what is problem .This code do not sort the dict.it is average of csv file with the names.

```py
import collections
import csv
from statistics import mean
from typing import OrderedDict
import operator

with open("mark.csv") as marks:
    reader=csv.reader(marks)
    for row in reader:
        list_marks=list()
        name=row[0]
        for grade in row[1:]:
            list_marks.append(float(grade))
            avg=mean(list_marks)
            dict_list={name:avg}
            res=sorted(dict_list.items(),key=lambda item:(item[1],item[0]))
        print(res)
```

Comment: You'll want to fix your indentation first, there's at least two syntax errors in this code. Also, you reset the value of `dict_list` on each iteration through the inner `for` loop. And you compute the average on each iteration of that loop as well, while it seems you want to do that on the outer loop. Instead of writing code with lots of errors and then asking why it doesn't work here, try to start with a simpler program that works and add logic as you go, so you know when you introduced an error. If you introduce an error and don't understand why it's wrong, that would be a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right.  Your major problems were indentation.  You can't compute the average until you have ALL the grades, and you were trying to do that for EVERY grade.  As @Grismar pointed out you were creating a new dictionary in each inner loop instead of adding a value to an existing dictionary.

Something like this shows what you were going for.

```
import csv
from statistics import mean

with open("mark.csv") as marks:
    reader=csv.reader(marks)
    dict_list = {}
    for row in reader:
        name=row[0]
        avg=mean(float(grade) for grade in row[1:])
        dict_list[name]=avg
res=sorted(dict_list.items(),key=lambda item:(item[1],item[0]))
print(res)
```